# How do I create

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a text file that needs to be read line by line and converted into a data frame with the 4 following columns

```
import re
import pandas as pd

with open('/Users/Desktop/Final Semester Fall 2022/archive/combined_data_1.txt',encoding='latin-1') as f:  
  for line in f:
    result = re.search(r"^(\d+),(\d+),(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/gm", line)
    if re.search(r"(^\d+):", line) is not None:
      movie_id = re.search(r"(^\d+):", line).group(1)
    elif result:
      customerid = result.group(1)
      rating = result.group(2)
      date = result.group(3) 
    else:
      continue 

  data_list = [customerid, rating, date, movie_id]    
  df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
  df1.to_csv(r'/Users/Desktop/Final Semester Fall 2022/archive/combineddata1.csv')
```

Im getting the following error:

How do I fix this error???

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `\d{2})/gm` I don't think you're allowed to embed flags in a regex like that in Python. You need to pass them as another argument to re.search: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#flags

Comment: Hi Sirod. Please edit your post to include the actual text of your data, and your error, and not images. The text is easier to read and we can easily copy-paste and try things ourselves as we work out solutions. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# read the csv file using read_csv, using ":" as a separator
# since there is only one colon ":" per movie, you end up with a row for movie following by rows for the rest of the data.

df=pd.read_csv(r'c:\csv.csv', sep=':', header=None, names=['col1', 'col2'])

# when there is no comma in a row, means its only a movie id, 
# so we populate the movieid column and downfill for all rows
df['MovieId'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col1'].str.contains(',')).ffill()

# split the data into CusotmerId, rating and date
df[['CustomerID','Rating','Date']] = df['col1'].str.split(',',expand=True)

# drop the unwanted columns and rows
df2=df[df['col1'].ne(df['MovieId'])].drop(columns=['col1','col2'])
df2
```

```
# sample created from the data you shared above as image

    MovieId     CustomerID  Rating  Date
1         1     1488844       3     2005-09-06
2         1     822109        5     2005-05-13
3         1     885013        4     2005-10-19
4         1     30878         4     2005-12-26
5         1     823519        3     2004-05-03
6         1     893988        3     2005-11-17
7         1     124105        4     2004-08-05
8         1     1248629       3     2004-04-22
9         1     1842128       4     2004-05-09
10        1     2238063       3     2005-05-11
11        1     1503895       4     2005-05-19
13        2     1288844       3     2005-09-06
14        2     832109        5     2005-05-13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse that structure quite easily (without regex, using a few lines of very readable vanilla Python) and build a dictionary while reading the data file. You can then convert the dictionary to a DataFrame in one go.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'MovieID':[], 'CustomerID':[],  'Rating':[],  'Date':[]}
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line: #skip empty lines
            if line.endswith(':'): #MovieID
                movie_id = line[:-1]
            else:
                customer_id, rating, date = line.split(',')
                df['MovieID'].append(movie_id)
                df['CustomerID'].append(customer_id)
                df['Rating'].append(rating)
                df['Date'].append(date)


df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)

   MovieID CustomerID Rating        Date
0        1    1488844      3  2005-09-06
1        1     822109      5  2005-05-13
2        1     885013      4  2005-10-19
3        1      30878      4  2005-12-26
4        2     823519      3  2004-05-03
5        2     893988      3  2005-11-17
6        2     124105      4  2004-08-05
7        2    1248629      3  2004-04-22
8        2    1842128      4  2004-05-09
9        3    2238063      3  2005-05-11
10       3    1503895      4  2005-05-19
11       3    1288844      3  2005-09-06
12       3     832109      5  2005-05-13
```

It hardly gets easier than this.

Answer (score 0):

#### An error in a regular expression

You've got the `NameError` because of `/gm` in the regular expression you use to identify `result`.

I suppose that `/gm` was coppied here by mistake. In other languages this could be GLOBAL and MULTILINE match modifiers, which by the way are not needed in this case. But in the python `re` module they are just three character. As far as you have no line with `/gm` inside, your `result` was allways `None`, so the `elif result: ...` block was never executed and variables `customerid`, `rating`, `date` were not initialized.

#### An error in working with variables

If you remove `/gm` from the first matching, you'll have another problem: the variables `customerid, rating, date, movie_id` are just strings, so the resulting data frame will reflect only the last record of the source file.

To avoid this we have to work with them as with a list-like structure. For example, in the code below, they are keys in the `data` dictionary, each referring to a separate list:

```
file_name = ...
data = {'movie_id': [], 'customerid': [], 'rating': [], 'date': []}    

with open(file_name, encoding='latin-1') as f:
    for line in f:
        result = re.search(r"^(\d+),(\d+),(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})", line)
        if re.search(r"(^\d+):", line) is not None:
            movie_id = re.search(r"(^\d+):", line).group(1)
        elif result:
            data['movie_id'].append(movie_id)
            data['customerid'].append(result.group(1))
            data['rating'].append(result.group(2))
            data['date'].append(result.group(3))
        else:
            continue 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Code with test data

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
1:
1488844,3,2005-09-06
822109,5,2005-05-13
885013,4,2005-10-19
30878,4,2005-12-26

2:
823519,3,2004-05-03
893988,3,2005-11-17
124105,4,2004-08-05
1248629,3,2004-04-22
1842128,4,2004-05-09

3:
2238063,3,2005-05-11
1503895,4,2005-05-19
1288844,3,2005-09-06
832109,5,2005-05-13
'''

file_name = "data.txt"
with open(file_name, 'tw', encoding='latin-1') as f:
    f.write(data)

data = {'movie_id': [], 'customerid': [], 'rating': [], 'date': []}    
with open(file_name, encoding='latin-1') as f:
    for line in f:
        result = re.search(r"^(\d+),(\d+),(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})", line)
        if re.search(r"(^\d+):", line) is not None:
            movie_id = re.search(r"(^\d+):", line).group(1)
        elif result:
            data['movie_id'].append(movie_id)
            data['customerid'].append(result.group(1))
            data['rating'].append(result.group(2))
            data['date'].append(result.group(3))
        else:
            continue 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(file_name[:-3] + 'csv', index=False)
```

#### An alternative

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, names = ['customerid', 'rating', 'date'])
df.insert(0, 'movie_id', pd.NA)
isnot_movie_id = ~df['customerid'].str.endswith(':')
df['movie_id'] = df['customerid'].mask(isnot_movie_id).ffill().str[:-1]
df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```